# DataReport Paisagem VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou usando o DataReport do vb6 com orientação em modo paisagem, assim:

```
RptFPagamentoDetalhe.Orientation = rptOrientLandscape
RptFPagamentoDetalhe.Show vbModal
```

Funciona normalmente no pc de desenvolvimento, com vb6 e o service pack 6 instalado, mas, ao gerar o setup, e instalar as vezes funciona em algumas máquinas e outras vezes recebo a mensagem:

```
Report Width is larger than paper width
```

Sendo que não posso instalar o Service Pack em uma maquina que nao tenha o vb instalado, como solucionar isso?

Vlw

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Posso estar enganado amigo, mas pode ser que o problema esteja relacionado com o tamanho do papel configurado na impressora padrão instalada na máquina.

Veja estes artigos da Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/261193

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197915

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ... ou a impressora padrão é uma do tipo impressora térmica, com papel reduzido.